# Android Service: is contract for Service.OnRebind() honored in emulator?

Tags: android

It is not clear to me that the contract for `Service.OnRebind()` / `Service.OnUnbind()` is faithfully honored for the emulator.  I have
a Service that needs to run for all Activities.  The way I pull this
off is for each `Activity.onStart()` to invoke `bindService()`, and for
each `Activity.onStop()` to invoke `unbindService()`.

Well, this sort of works, but inconsistently:

- If my main Activity starts another activity, then `unbindService()` is called from main's `Activity.onStop()`, as expected.  However, when the next Activity is started, and the call to `Activity.onStart()` leads to an invocation of `bindService()`,  then `Service.OnRebind()` is not called.
- If I press the Home button and the entire app is stopped, then the current `Activity's` `onStop()` is called, properly leading to an invocation of `unbindService()`.  When I resume the app (by clicking on it on the app screen), `Service.OnRebind()` is called.

Is this a result of a bug in the emulator?  Is the Service contract correctly documented in Google's docs?

NOTE:  this example assumes `startService()` was called to initiate a persistent service.  If `startService()` is not called, then `Service.OnRebind()` is just never called, even when `bindService()` is called.

Comment: from the **same** client (Activity) call bindService > unbindService > bindService and see what happens: it should explain everything

Comment: I think I found the issue.  I was under the assumption that a precondition of any Activity.onStart() being called is that the previous Activity.onStop() is called.  Evidently, that is a false assumption.  IE, if Activity A starts Activity B, then it is possible for A.onStop() to be called AFTER B.onStart() is called.  I'll wait for other comments before posting a formal answer.

Comment: this order has nothing to do with `onRebind` being called or not

Comment: It may not affect `onRebind`.  But it apparently does affect some kind of reference counter built into the Service.

Comment: "reference counter"? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Calls to `bindService()` get called when `Activity.onStart()` is called.  Likewise, calls to `unbindService()` get called when `Activity.onStop()` is called.  Suppose `Activity.onStart()` is successively called without any intervening invocations of `Activity.onStop()`.  What happens for me is that `Service.OnBind()` is not called for the 2nd `Activity.onStart()`.  This is a problem for me because the `Intent` going into the `Service` on the latter call actually contains new data.

Comment: bound services should not use Intent extras at all, they are "bound" so client can directly pass data to them, not using extras (are you using "local bound service" ?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82729/discussion-between-kode-charlie-and-pskink).

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/service_binding_tree_lifecycle.png, note that it is per **client** (Activity), that is the same applies to Activity A and B

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug in the emulator. The emulator runs the same Android code as a phone does, albiet much slower and with fake sensors.